# LaTeX - including .bib file not working properly

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using a simple LaTeX file `main.tex` where am including a bib file and referring to its references, but reference numbers and references are not displayed, instead there is symbol **?**. I want to print references whom I have referred to under the section `Bibliography` and reference number such as `[1]`. How can I make this code work as I want? Am using Windows 8, Texmaker 4.0.4 and MiKTeX 2.9. Here is the code.
main.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[german, english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\title{My Article}
\author{Nobody Jr.}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

Blablabla said Nobody ~\cite{Nobody06}.

\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{local}

\end{document}
```

local.bib

```
@misc{ Nobody06,
       author = "Nobody Jr",
       title = "My Article",
       year = "2006" }
```

Comment: Did you run `bibtex` on the `.aux` file?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yes. Now I run bibtex on .aux file then run LaTeX on main.tex, but no change. I had executed a similar program on Windows 7 before (dont remember the version of LaTeX), it was working without running bibtex on .aux file. I executed another example from  (http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/documents/bibtex/) and followed the instructions, but again no references are printed.

Comment: There is no error and the citation works with the files you posted you need `pdflatex main;bibtex main; pdflatex main; pdflatex main` That is two runs of latex after bibtex